# How to rewrite a Adaptive Card Submit Action for MSTeams also working in Web Chat?

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, web-chat

Hi i'm using adaptive Cards and want to generate a Submit Action which works in MS Teams as well as in Webchat.

In Emulator this works fine. After i'm clicking the Button its like the user would type in
"Test" in the chat.

```json
"actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Test",
      "data": "Test"
    }
```

This doesnt work in MS Teams. How to bring this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My [blog post](https://github.com/v-kydela/BotBlog/blob/master/Blog%20-%20Adaptive%20Cards.md) explains that if you want to use a string submit action you will need to do it differently in Web Chat and Teams:

> [There is some special Adaptive Card functionality that is specific to
> the Microsoft Teams
> channel.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-actions#adaptive-cards-actions)
> You can supply a special property with the name `msteams` to the
> object in an object submit action's `data` property in order to access
> this functionality. By doing so, you can get a submit action to behave
> like an action of your choosing. The object you put in the `msteams`
> property must have a `type` property in order to specify the submit
> action's special behavior.
>
> When the `type` property is
> ["messageBack"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-actions#adaptive-cards-with-messageback-action) the submit action will behave like a `messageBack` card action, which
> is like a combination of `imBack` and `postBack`. This means you can
> specify both visible text that will be displayed in the conversation
> history as well as invisible data that gets sent to the bot behind the
> scenes.
>
> ```json
> {
>   "type": "Action.Submit",
>   "title": "Click me for messageBack",
>   "data": {
>     "msteams": {
>         "type": "messageBack",
>         "displayText": "I clicked this button",
>         "text": "text to bots",
>         "value": "{\"bfKey\": \"bfVal\", \"conflictKey\": \"from value\"}"
>     },
>     "extraData": {}
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> The `displayText` string is what gets displayed in the conversation
> history. The `text` string will populate the activity's `text`
> property but will be invisible to the user. The activity's `value`
> property will get populated in the usual way by combining the values
> of any input fields with any additional properties in the `data`
> property's object, but it will also include any properties that have
> been serialized into the `value` property of the `msteams` property's
> object.
>
> When the `type` property is
> ["imBack"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-actions#adaptive-cards-with-imback-action)
> the submit action will behave like a `imBack` card action. This of
> course will work similarly to a string submit action but it has the
> advantage of not breaking when the card contains input fields, though
> the input fields' values will not be sent to bot when the user clicks
> this action and neither will any additional properties you put in the
> `data` property's object. Also, Microsoft Teams does not support
> string submit actions at the time of this writing, so you will need to
> use this special Teams feature if you want to simulate string submit
> actions.
>
> ```json
> {
>   "type": "Action.Submit",
>   "title": "Click me for imBack",
>   "data": {
>     "msteams": {
>         "type": "imBack",
>         "value": "Text to reply in chat"
>     },
>     "extraData": "(this will be ignored)"
>   }
> }
> ```

If you want to have the same submit action work the same way in both channels, it will need to be an object submit action. If you want a string submit action to work on both channels then your bot will need to check which channel the activity came from and react accordingly.

Comment: Have you got a sample where the bot is checking the channel?

Comment: Use the activity's [`ChannelId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/azure/bot-service/bot-service-resources-identifiers-guide#channel-id) property. There are several [samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/21b9cfa59a8ae552130676361d0c2218ccb4b958/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/05.multi-turn-prompt/Dialogs/UserProfileDialog.cs#L109-L115) that show this if you'd like to search for "ChannelId" in that solution, and it's even shown in this readme: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/49.qnamaker-all-features

Comment: That link is no longer working, also the answer should be in SO and not in an external link.

Comment: @JoãoAbrantes Thanks for pointing out that the bot blog is down. I updated the answer with your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following sample adaptive card Json,

`{"type":"AdaptiveCard","version":"1.0","body":[{"type":"TextBlock","text":"Imback Button"}],"$schema":"http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json","actions":[{"type":"Action.Submit","title":"Can you Help me","data":{"msteams":{"type":"imBack","value":"Can you help me"}}}]}`

you can test adaptive cards in App studio app in Teams.

Hope this will help you.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi Krishna, thanks in MS Teams works now but not in WebChat. Is there a way to get it to work for both? Or do i have to set up a new Bot?