# Can't get imBack to work on Adaptive Cards that are set up to work with teams

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, web-chat

My bot has a menu card which I recently discovered doesn't work with teams. I want to use the imBack method to have the message show up in the chat. On their own, I can accomplish this with the following:

```js
// For directline/webchat
"type": "Action.Submit",
"title": "Get Order Status",
"data": "Get Order Status"
},

// For MS Teams
"type": "Action.Submit",
"title": "Get Order Status",
"data": {
    "msteams": {
        "type": "imBack",
        "value": "Get Order Status"
    },
},
```

However, if I use the directline/webchat version, I get a general bot error in Teams (I believe the error is because the button doesn't create an imBack message, thus LUIS query is empty and all my code referencing LUIS attributes like topIntent and score fail. Due to bot design LUIS needs to be called every turn.) Likewise, if I use Teams version I get a general bot error in directline/webchat for the same reason. At first I tried to add additional objects like the one I created for msteams for other channel IDs, but that didn't change the behavior. Based on the information [here](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/5396), I was able to add the text attribute and copy it from context.activity.value to context.activity.text via the following:

```js
// In my card definition
"type": "Action.Submit",
"title": "Get Order Status",
"data": {
    "msteams": {
        "type": "imBack",
        "value": "Get Order Status"
    },
    "text": "Get Order Status"
},

// In my onMessage handler
if (context.activity.channelData.postBack) {
    context.activity.text = context.activity.value.text;
}
```

When I implement it this way, it does *technically* work in both channels. However, the menu selection (in this case **Get Order Status**) does not appear in the chat window as a message from the user (and by extension, doesn't show in the chat transcript) for directline/webchat channel (it does for Teams channel). I would really like this to behave in the same way as it does if I just have the text at the attribute for data in my directline/webchat only implementation. Is there any way to set up the card (e.g. via different format of the data object to have different data sent based on channel) and/or onMessage handler so that, on button click, the text is displayed in the chat window regardless of channel, and by extension that text will go through LUIS so that I don't get bot errors due to null LUIS attributes?

The one thought I had was to create a separate card helper for Teams and call it from my menu intent based on channelId, but I'd like a more elegant solution than that if it is possible, especially since I have several different cards with submit buttons like this.

Comment: This question is hard to follow and I suspect there's at least one piece of information you forgot to include. You start by saying you have a working solution, and then without explanation you say you've tried something different. It's unclear what problem you're trying to solve, and there seem to be several possibilities at the moment. Are you perhaps saying the problem is that imBack actions have no display text in Teams? Are you perhaps saying that you don't want two different formats for your two channels? Either way, it's unclear what behavior is different between your two code blocks.

Comment: imBack has no display text in directline. If I go with a format that displays it in directline, it doesn't work in teams. And if I have a format that displays it in teams, it doesn't work in directline. But if it doesn't display in teams, the whole thing errors out.

Comment: I'm sorry but that still doesn't explain the problem. I want to be clear that when I said "display text" I meant that the message is rendered in the transcript window and I wasn't necessarily referring to the `displayText` property of card actions. When you say imBack are you talking about string submit actions or actual imBack card actions (which are only in Bot Framework cards and not Adaptive Cards)? Have you read this blog post? https://blog.botframework.com/2019/07/02/using-adaptive-cards-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/

Comment: If you have a format that works on each channel, why not just have your bot send a different card based on the channel ID? And what do you mean by "if it doesn't display in teams, the whole thing errors out"? Are you talking about the card getting displayed or the action message getting rendered? And what is the "whole thing" and what does it mean for it to error out? I think you should seriously consider rewriting your question to explain what you're actually trying to do and why.

Comment: I will try your first suggestion and also try to edit the question later. I was hoping instead of having separate card formats that I could have a single format that would work across multiple channels. That's what adaptive cards are supposed to be for, right?

Comment: OK I tried to add more details for clarity. As mentioned, I'd prefer NOT to create separate cards based on channel, as if I change menu options I'll have to change them in multiple places, but if that is the only way to accomplish this I will do it. I don't mind if the card renders differently per channel, I think that's the point that adaptive cards will "adapt" to the channel, I just am trying to determine a way to make the card functional in multiple channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your card contains no inputs then I suspect you want a hero card and not an Adaptive Card. An imBack in a hero card will automatically work the way you want in both Web Chat and Teams. While Adaptive Cards are meant to adapt to the styles of their hosts, there is no builtin "imBack" feature of Adaptive Cards. String submit actions are a feature of Web Chat, and Bot Framework actions in Adaptive Cards are a feature of Teams. You're trying to get Adaptive Cards to do something that they can't do by themselves, and so you'll need to take your specific channel into consideration if you want to do that.

From this answer: [How to rewrite a Adaptive Card Submit Action for MSTeams also working in Web Chat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61523621/how-to-rewrite-a-adaptive-card-submit-action-for-msteams-also-working-in-web-cha/61528151#61528151)

> My blog post explains that if you want to use a string submit action you will need to do it differently in Web Chat and Teams: https://blog.botframework.com/2019/07/02/using-adaptive-cards-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/
>
> If you want to have the same submit action work the same way in both channels, it will need to be an object submit action. If you want a string submit action to work on both channels then your bot will need to check which channel the activity came from and react accordingly.

Comment: I was actually using hero cards before, but for 6-8 actions like I have, formatting was not good. But I get the takeaway here. Based on my requirement, I either need to use hero card for teams and adaptive card for other channels, or use two different schemas for adaptive cards based on channel. Either way I will need to have channel specific behavior set. Thanks for the research into this.

Comment: It's always good to mention what you've tried before in questions like these

Comment: Sure, I should have mentioned that, since technically hero cards do work fine across both channels. They just don't have the two column format necessary plus I didn't feel they looked right in Teams with 6+ buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Though Kyle's answer is correct depending on your use case, for me the proper solution ended up being to switch between the card helper functions based on channel, at the point where the helper is called. So as in my original question, I still am using

```js
// For directline/webchat
"type": "Action.Submit",
"title": "Get Order Status",
"data": "Get Order Status"
},

// For MS Teams
"type": "Action.Submit",
"title": "Get Order Status",
"data": {
    "msteams": {
        "type": "imBack",
        "value": "Get Order Status"
    },
},
```

but I am building the cards in two completely separate helpers, for me called `GetMenuCard` and `GetMenuCardTeams`. Then, everywhere I need to display the menu card I do this check first:

```js
if (context.activity.channelId == 'meteams') {
    var menuCard = CardHelper.GetMenuCardTeams(cardOptions);
} else {
    var menuCard = CardHelper.GetMenuCard(cardOptions);
}
```

Note that you need to adjust the variable based on where you are doing the check. `context.activity.channelId` works most places. If you are in a waterfall, you'll need `step.context.activity.channelId` (or whatever you name your step context variable, step and stepContext seem to be the most common people use). In my QnA dialog I'm not passing context, just activity, but that still works via `activity.channelId` (that helper is just passing back an answer, not sending the activity, which is why I don't need context). So you don't need a context to set the helper function, but you do at least need activity or a way to get the channel ID.

I've implemented this and found it to be the best solution to my intended use case. But if you'd rather not mess with all the if statements and just want a single card to work as expected in both channels, Kyle's answer to use Hero Cards is the better approach.

Answer (score 0):

"imBack" property works well in MS Teams. It is better to keep the property "data" different for webcat and msteams. For MS Teams, use the structure:

```
 "msteams": {
    "type": "imBack",
     "value": <value>
             }
       }
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this format, but have separate objects for msteams and other channels under data? I tried with "emulator" as another object key under data but it didn't work. Would be so much better if I could define multiple objects per channel instead of needed two completely separate card helpers. @Kyle-Delaney?

Comment: No, msteams is special